# Adding :id to guarded component path causes infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[This stackblitz demo should not render](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-slice-demo-guard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts) because of the `:id` path variable in the route to the guarded `HelloComponent`.

```
{ path: ':id', component: HelloComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }];
```

If `:id` is removed, then the `login` view renders, since both paths will be guarded, but if the `:id` variable is added back to the path, the demo spins forever.

Is this a bug or am I violating some router principle by adding `:id` to this location?

Note that I replaced the `ViewBook` component with a `HelloComponent` just for trouble shooting purposes.  The books module is lazy and the way that this is supposed to work is that if the user authenticates and selects a book in search the book can be shown with the path `books/4545342`, which would trigger the `:id` path, but if just `books` is requested, without a path parameter then the book collection is shown.

[I'm using this demo as a reference point](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbooks-routing.module.ts).  Is uses a essentially the same routing configuration.

[I tried flipping the `path` parameters here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store-route-test?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbooks-routing.module.ts).  It seems in older versions of Angular the order does not matter, but now it does.

[Filed a bug report here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the router, you have to be careful where you import modules. Ideally, you won't import a lazy loaded module in your application anywhere.

In your case, you're importing the book module into your app module. This adds the routes to the router config at the root level. The router does fancy unknown-to-me things with lazy loaded modules. Routes that cannot be activated won't be added to the config.

See new config after removing book module from app module:

```
0: {path: "login", component: ƒ}
1: {path: "", redirectTo: "books", pathMatch: "full"}
2: {path: "books", loadChildren: ƒ, _loadedConfig: LoadedRouterConfig}
3: {path: "**", component: ƒ}
```

VS before the move:

```
0: {path: ":id", component: ƒ}
1: {path: "", component: ƒ}
2: {path: "login", component: ƒ}
3: {path: "", redirectTo: "books", pathMatch: "full"}
4: {path: "books", loadChildren: ƒ, _loadedConfig: LoadedRouterConfig}
5: {path: "**", component: ƒ}
```

To fix: simply don't import your book module in the app module. In your case, you'll need to import the HttpClientModule in your book module.

Comment: Created another Feature Request per you answer: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28248

Comment: That's a good idea! It'll be interesting to see what they say as I am not familiar enough with the multi providers and/or how to detect if the provider already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pay attention I change the order, and added `pathMatch` to `''` route,

```
{ path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: ':id', component: HelloComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

- if the issue is not solved let me know to delete my answer

Comment: IIUC the more specific paths are supposed to be first.  So for example if we added `find` then that would come before `:id`.  In this case the empty `''` is being triggered first, and now the `:id` path will never fire.  Reviewers let me know if I'm wrong about this and I can accept the answer.   Its an attempt at refactoring this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbooks-routing.module.ts  In it the `:id` path comes before the `''` path.

Comment: Also this is what the documentation says: The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

Comment: I added a link to the demo routing that works in the question.  I think some of the core semantics of angular have been refactored since the demo was published, because `canActivate` can no longer be added in conjunction with `loadChildren` for example.

Comment: In an older version of angular, it seems the order does not matter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store-route-test?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbooks-routing.module.ts

Comment: Filed a bug report here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27920

Comment: @Ole as summary, is your issue reproducible on https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fbooks-routing.module.ts ?

Comment: Yes - If you click this demo you'll see that it just spins forever.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-slice-demo-guard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts

Comment: It also does not shutdown after the tab is closed.  I have to go to the system monitor and kill the process.

Comment: Oh - Ooops - I tested your link - which is the original ngrx demo I was refactoring.  I tried switching the paths in that demo, and the demo still works.  It's a fairly old demo.  The demo works with a `canActivate` guard on the `loadChildren` path, and that no longer works in the current version of angular either.

Comment: So to summarize I think the Angular router has gone through some refactoring, and now things that should work, are broken.